# Identity Server + ionic + OpenID Hybrid flow

Tags: ionic-framework, openid, ionic2, identityserver3, identityserver4

I can't find any example for this kinda solution. Is it doable ? In my knowledge, it should be, but I haven't seen anyone doing this. Any downside for this way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server + Ionic + OpenID Hybrid Flow is possible.  For OIDC Hybrid Flow, you have to configure the response_type and scope accordingly.   Example: configure 
response_type: "id_token token",
scope: "openid profile",

For how to configure you can refer [Configuring Identity Server with Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879777/configure-identity-server-4-with-ionic-2), where the response_type is "id_token token" and scope is "openid" which is OIDC Hybrid Flow. You can specify the response_type as per your need.  For the supported response_type check [this link](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html#MultiValueResponseTypes)