# Configure Identity Server 4 With Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to configure Identity Server to work with Ionic 2. I'm a bit confused on how to configure the Redirect urls.  For when I'm testing in the browser.

I'm in the process of updating and integrating an OIDC Cordova component.
The old component git hub is here:
 https://github.com/markphillips100/oidc-cordova-demo

I've created a typescript provider and registered it with my app.module.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Oidc from "oidc-client";
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { environment } from "../rules/environments/environment";

export class UserInfo {
    user: Oidc.User = null;
    isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
}

@Injectable()
export class OidcClientProvider   {

    USERINFO_CHANGED_EVENT_NAME: string = ""
    userManager: Oidc.UserManager;
    settings: Oidc.UserManagerSettings;
    userInfo: UserInfo = new UserInfo();
    constructor(public events:Events) {

        this.settings = {
            //authority: "https://localhost:6666",
            authority: environment.identityServerUrl,
            client_id: environment.clientAuthorityId,
            //This doesn't work
            post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost/oidc",
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost/oidc",
            response_type: "id_token token",
            scope: "openid profile",

            automaticSilentRenew: true,
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true,
            //popupNavigator: new Oidc.CordovaPopupNavigator(),
            //iframeNavigator: new Oidc.CordovaIFrameNavigator(),
        }

        this.initialize();
    }

    userInfoChanged(callback: Function) {
        this.events.subscribe(this.USERINFO_CHANGED_EVENT_NAME, callback);
    }

    signinPopup(args?): Promise<Oidc.User> {
        return this.userManager.signinPopup(args);
    }

    signoutPopup(args?) {
        return this.userManager.signoutPopup(args);
    }

    protected initialize() {

        if (this.settings == null) {
            throw Error('OidcClientProvider required UserMangerSettings for initialization')
        }

        this.userManager = new Oidc.UserManager(this.settings);
        this.registerEvents();
    }

    protected notifyUserInfoChangedEvent() {
        this.events.publish(this.USERINFO_CHANGED_EVENT_NAME);
    }

    protected clearUser() {
        this.userInfo.user = null;
        this.userInfo.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.notifyUserInfoChangedEvent();
    }

    protected addUser(user: Oidc.User) {
        this.userInfo.user = user;
        this.userInfo.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.notifyUserInfoChangedEvent();
    }

    protected registerEvents() {
        this.userManager.events.addUserLoaded(u => {
            this.addUser(u);
        });

        this.userManager.events.addUserUnloaded(() => {
            this.clearUser();
        });

        this.userManager.events.addAccessTokenExpired(() => {
            this.clearUser();
        });

        this.userManager.events.addSilentRenewError(() => {
            this.clearUser();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how I would configure the redirect urls so I can authenticate normally in the browser.  Normally you would configure a redirect 
url to take your process the token and claims after login.

```
this.settings = {
        authority: environment.identityServerUrl,
        client_id: environment.clientAuthorityId,
        post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8100/oidc",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8100/oidc",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile AstootApi",

        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        filterProtocolClaims: true,
        loadUserInfo: true,
        //popupNavigator: new Oidc.CordovaPopupNavigator(),
        //iframeNavigator: new Oidc.CordovaIFrameNavigator(),
    }
```

Ionic 2 doesn't use urls for routing, Supposing I have a component `AuthenticationPage` which handles storing the authentication token.
How can I configured a redirect url so it navigates to the authentication page, so I can test this in the browser?

Comment: Did you use inappbrowser plugin to access the idp?

Comment: The OIDC provider handles that for you although I haven’t tested it on native yet because I changed to target PWA.  If any of this information proves to be useful please remember to upvote. If you have any other questions just post me a comment and I’ll help you out the best I can

Comment: I've done a simple implementation which doesn't work on native as it's not hooking into inappbrowser. Works on Web Page but not native. At this stage ionic seems less fit for purpose if you want to use custom idp

Comment: @Aeseir see the two lines of commented out code in my question, those two lines of code supposedly set up oidc to use pop up navigator for the idp.  But if your working on angular 4 there is a better OIDC manager to use.

Comment: @Aeseir did you check to make sure the in app browser works before attempting to hook into OIDC? I remember there were a bunch of steps to get the in app browser working for mobile.  Also are you testing on iOS or Android I know iOS had some issues in the past

Comment: So those two lines will hook into inappbrowser? I've used other oidc classes. The problem is they use router which is not part of the ionic package

Comment: Testing on Android. Trying to search for material that shows off there are any steps to hook in

Comment: @Aeseir yeah I didn’t want to use the router either. So I dropped the callback on the landing page.  Lemme post some more code in my answer hold on

Comment: So you moved away from oidc and using something different now?

Comment: @Aeseir I've updated the answer to show a more full example.  I haven't tested on any natives yet but if you open a question I'll support it because I'm sure Ill run into these issues when I start testing Mobile.

Comment: @Aeseir No, I was saying I didn't want to use the router either, so I just dropped set my call back as the landing page, I've provided an example in my answer below

Comment: Yea i kicked off another stackoverflow question specifically regarding this issue. My point is have you moved away from oidc-client-js package and using another one? the ones dedicated to angular rely on @angular/router, which when installed causes errors on Ionic as its not compatible. The other option which i am less inclined to do is create a restful login on IdentityServer4. That may be messy though.

Comment: Btw im going to look into ResourceOwner flow as alternative and implement my own front end. It is not recommended way but may enable for restful signin and signout. Keep in touch for updates (i'll get a github repo up)

Comment: @Aeseir I'm trying to boot up android, just need to do some updates

Comment: ok, keen to view the results. I just had a look at AppAuth-JS as well (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS) not sure if that can help as well

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Were u able to get it ot work in native?

Comment: @Aeseir I built a sample project yesterday.  But I haven’t tested on native,  I’m working out a few minor details because I have to launch web soon. But maybe tonight?

Comment: i've tried couple libraries and i've reached out ot Ionic, so far nothing. Which is astounding. Maybe we should be looking at it from point of ID4, create some type of restful login capability. I'll head off in a bit, will touch base with you tomorrow night. I've just done a solution in Xamarin in fraction of the time.

Comment: @Aeseir Ok I’ll make a post tonight. I’m pretty sure I have a working example, I just have to play with configuring the in app browser

Comment: i've just tried using openid-client but that hasn't hit the mark yet. Did u have any luck?

Comment: @Aeseir I’m having issues on my end I’ve opened a bounty as well about something different

Comment: I managed to get auth to launch on openid-client. Need to generate pkce to complete process. I'll let you know how I go

Comment: Do you have a repo?

Comment: Not yet uploaded. If I get it working I'll upload it. I can upload dummy non working if you want

Comment: It’s up to you, I’m having trouble getting my emulator to boot on my computer, so I don’t know how much help I’ll be until I fix it

Comment: If you have it in repo I could test it. I got few devices hooked up

Comment: btw i started a new issue around this on Ionic github page https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14499 if you want to add weight to it

Comment: @Aeseir I have OIDC working in the browser, but your question is native specific correct?

Comment: Not really. Have you tested it in emulator or device. Browser works on desktop but not devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I had to do a few things to get this working.
I didn't realize at first but My Redirect Urls had to be matching for what my client has stored in identity server.

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "myApp",
    ClientName = "app client",
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8166/" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8166/" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:8166" },
    //...
}
```

So the OIDC client in Typescript needed to be updated too.

```
this.settings = {
    authority: environment.identityServerUrl,
    client_id: environment.clientAuthorityId,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8166/",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8166/",
    response_type: "id_token token",
}
```

Also since I didn't feel like setting up routing in Ionic I needed to figure out  a way to a url to communicate with Ionic (For Browser testing purpose, normal commucation will be done through cordova).

So I pointed the redirct url to be the url ionic is hosting my application and on app.Component.ts in the Constructor I added code to try to get my authentication token.

```
constructor(
  public platform: Platform,
  public menu: MenuController,
  public oidcClient: OidcClientProvider
)
{
  //Hack: since Ionic only has 1 default address, attempt to verify if this is a call back before calling 
   this.authManager.verifyLoginCallback().then((isSuccessful) => {
     if (!isSuccessful) {
        this.authManager.IsLoggedIn().then((isLoggedIn) => {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
              return;
          }

          this.nav.setRoot(LoginComponent)
        });
     }
  });
}
```

**Edit** Verify login call back should just the oidc client call back which will read the token from the get params

```
verifyLoginCallback(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.oidcClient.userManager.signinPopupCallback()
        .then(user => {
            return this.loginSuccess(user).
                then(() => true,
                    () => false);
    }, err => { console.log(err); return false; });
}
```

**NOTE** the Login component is just a modal which represents login landing page, which just uses a login button to initialize the popup.  You can hook this into any user driven event to trigger the login, but you must use a user driven event if you want to support the web without triggering a popup blocker

```
<ion-footer no-shadow>
  <ion-toolbar no-shadow position="bottom">
    <button ion-button block (click)="login()">Login</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>

login(): Promise<any> {
    return this.oidcClient.signinPopup().then((user) => {
        this.events.publish(environment.events.loginSuccess);
    }).catch((e) => { console.log(e); });
}
```

I'm sure there is a better do the redirect to a different route, This is just a quick and dirty hack

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a repository you could share to demonstrate your app setup? As someone who is getting into this now, figuring out the authentication is my biggest issue.

Comment: @Aeseir I don’t have a shareable repo, what issues are you having? Almost all of the code is there to get it working

Comment: I'm new to ionic so I'm gathering information on key topics that I need to have proper authenticated app

Comment: @Aeseir why do you want to use a token server and not just authenticate with jwt

Comment: not so much the type of token as to how it all works. So i am trying to figure out how the IdentityServer4 setup needs to be for mobile app authentication as well as token type i need to use. I read that PKCE is the type we should be using. Whatever the access token given will be what i use as bearer token to get data from api server.

Comment: Is anyone able to provide an implementation of what verifyLoginCallback() might look like

Comment: Awesome! Not using popup, but still worked! Thanks! Upvoted

Comment: @JoshL thank you, what issues are you have, do you have IdentityServer Set to redirect to your home page as the callback?

Comment: The flow should work like so.  You open a popup to your token server, user logs in, token server validates login and send the token parameters as get params back to the client.  The the oidcmanager reads the token from the get params and then you can store it some where. If you Identify where there issue is I can help you